# Dynamically loading simple content partial in a view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I followed [this tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy) to build a simple functionality: click on a button to load content stored in a partial. I'd like to later use it in various places where I don't want to overload views with information to keep them light, but allow the user to access the information if necessary.

Following the tutorial this is the code:

```
# in view: knowledge/index.html.haml

.container 
  .row
    .col-xs-12
      = link_to 'Show more info', fetch_adus_path, :remote => true
      #adus
```

-

```
# in: config/routes.rb

get '/knowledge/fetch_adus', to: 'knowledge#selected_adus', as: 'fetch_adus'
```

-

```
# my partial: knowledge/_adus_all.html.haml

%p Content will be added here
```

-

```
# in: knowledge_controller.rb

def selected_adus
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

-

```
# knowledge/selected_adus.js.haml

$("#adus").html("#{escape_javascript(render partial: 'adus_all')}");
```

On the knowledge (index) page - when I hover over 'Show more info' Chrome indicates it should link to localhost:3000/knowledge/fetch_adus but when I click on it nothing happens. I get an error in console:

> GET http://localhost:3000/knowledge/fetch_adus 500 (Internal Server Error)      jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:10255

which (after clicking) leads to this line of code:

> xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );

To provide a bit more context, when I click the link twice I get a simpler error:

> knowledge/fetch_adus Failed to load resource: the server responded
>   with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

which leads to this rails error page:

> ActionController::UnknownFormat in KnowledgeController#selected_adus
>
> ActionController::UnknownFormat
>
> Extracted source (around line #25):
>
> respond_to do |format|

I'm new to rails, if anyone has any idea how to fix it or if there's any other way of building the functionality I described I will greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: show the server log when the request is being made and the full controller code

Comment: @dstull I checked the log and found out what was the issue. In the partial file I had some code that was commented out but weirdly it was causing a template error. Removed it and both js solutions (escape_javascript and j render - translated to haml - worked). Somehow I didn't check the log before. Adding that to my personal debug-scenario checklist. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simpler than expected. Thanks to @dstull I checked the log and found out what was the issue. In the partial I had some code that was commented out but weirdly it was causing a template error. Removed it and both js solutions (escape_javascript and j render - translated to haml - worked). It is a good practice to always check logs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with your knowledge/selected_adus.js.haml file

Try reformatting `$("#adus").html("#{escape_javascript(render partial: 'adus_all')}");` to `$("#adus").html("<%= j render partial: 'knowledge/adus_all' %>");`

Comment: Thanks @Zubin - it appears that both solutions were correct and the problem was elsewhere - in a code that was commented out but still caused a template error.